# TFS2010 merge between a branch and a trunk never converges

Tags: .net, tfs, merge

We have a TFS2010 main trunk and several branches.

I am trying to bring trunk and branch1 to a state when there are no more changes left by merging from trunk to branch1, checking in and then merging from branch1 to trunk and checking in.

However, after that if I try to see if there is still anything possible to merge either way TFS keeps on showing me the same set of about 15 files that require merging. After merge is performed the files are nowhere to find on the file system, but TFS is still sure these 15 files are to be merged.

I went in cycles many times merging one into the other and vice-versa but nothing seem to fix it. And I am not the first one in our team to experience this bug/feature.

May be I am missing something obvious? Anyone any ideas why TFS is behaving so weirdly? Is there a way to put an end to this anarchy of endless pointless merges?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few possibilities:

1) (forgive me if it is stating the obvious) When you merge, the changes are made locally in your workspace, and are not committed to the TFS database. When the merge is completed you need to check in the changes before they will be reflected in TFS and (hopefully) disappear from the "things still to be merged" lists.

2) Have you got more than one workspace? (e.g I once tried using a normal Dev workspace for the trunk, and a special Merging workspace that mapped in both the trunk and the branch)

If you merge into one workspace, the merged files will only appear in your pending changes for that workspace. Note that the Source Control explorer and the Pending Chnages windows both have their own Workspace drop-down, and if you switch workspaces in your SC explorer (to do the merge), your pending changes will not be switched over, and so will be looking at a different workspace. This one caught me out a couple of times ("I've done a merge, but TFS hasn't changed any of the files. What's going on?!")

3) Sometimes TFS appears to get confused and behaves erratically. With each new version of TFS this gets significantly better, but it still happens to me occasionally in 2010. (This is not the answer you want to hear, I know :-)

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply, though it does not answer my problem unfortunately: 1)As I explicitly written in my question I do always checkin after each merge step to both trunk and branch1. This does not help, after I check if there is anything to merge between the two TFS again brings up all the same files. 2)I have only one workspace. 3)Sadly, it seems to me that something went really badly with TFS and it indeed got very confused. So my question is how can I get it back straight?

Answer (score 0):

The one case that is possible outside the wonderful brief that Jason has highlighted.

Have you previously used the tf.exe rollback **/keepmergehistory[1]** command on the changesets in the main or branch1? Read more about the tf.exe rollback command here http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/27/how-to-undo-a-changeset-using-tf.exe-rollback.aspx

[1] - Specify this option if you want future merges between the same source and the same target to exclude the changes that you are rolling back.

If so, you can use tf.exe merge /force http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=VS.100).aspx which forces a merge between the 2 branches. But make sure you check in after the merge (when there is conflict after the merge, unless you resolve the conflict and check in, the changes remain checked out) and if you do a view history after the merge to the branch you are able to see the new changeset, verify the changeset details to make sure that the merge took place correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you've changed the file in both branches and merge back and forth, TFS does not always (I still haven't found out when and why) update the common ancestor for the files making it think they are still both changed.

To correct this issue I always just perform a merge and choose "Take source branch" for the conflicts, once I know that source and destination branches are already the same.

If anyone has a good explanation why this happens I'd be happy to hear it...